# How Square tin with side "6a" units after bending have length of a side of the square is "a" units?

Tags: derivatives

Suppose by using square tin sheet with side "6a units", make a topless box of maximum volume by cutting equal squares at the corners and removing them and then bending the tin so as to form the sides of the box.
What I don't understand is that how the length of a side of the square becomes "a units."?

Answer (score 1):

Let the side of the cut square be $x$. Then, the sides and height of the resultant cuboid will be $6a - 2x, 6a - 2x, x$.

Volume= $(6a - 2x)(6a - 2x) x = 4x (3a - x)^2$.

For maximum value of volume, $\frac{dv}{dx} = 0$.

$\Rightarrow 4(3a-x)^2 + 8x(3a-x)(-1) =0$

$\Rightarrow (3a-x)(3a-3x)=0$

Because $x=3a$ not possible as then two sides will have zero length, $x=a$ units.

Comment: Thank you @Rohan for helping..

Answer (score 1):

By cutting equal squares of side $x$ at the corners and removing them we can construct a box of dimensions $6a-2x$, $6a-2x$, $x$ with $0\leq x\leq 3a$.

Hence by [AGM-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#The_inequality) its volume is bounded by
$$V(x):=x(6a-2x)^2=2(2x)(3a-x)^2\leq 2\left(\frac{2x+(3a-x)+(3a-x)}{3}\right)^3=16a^3=V(a).$$
Moreover the equality holds iff $2x=3a-x$, that is $x=a$.

Comment: @Zonnie You are welcome! Any further doubt?

Comment: No.. That's so kind of you..